# When I click on a Spinner item, it will show a ListView

Tags: android, database, listview, android-spinner

I want to make an app which contains a Spinner and a ListView and when I click a Sinner item it will open a new ListView, no new Activity just to update the ListView from the database.

For instance, I have Europe and Africa in the Spinner and when I click Europe it will show me a ListView with the European countries, when I click Africa it will show me a ListView with the African countries.

I searched this on the internet, but I could not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to set up a spinner you need an adapter. Then you need to use an OnItemSelectedListener. Use this code:

```
    europeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.europeListView);
    africaListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.africaListView);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.countries, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            if(adapter.getItem(i) == "Europe"){

                europeListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                africaListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            } else if(adapter.getItem(i) == "Africa"){

                africaListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                europeListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Finally, make a string array called "countries" containing Europe and Africa in your strings.xml file like so:

```
<string-array name="countries">
    <item>Europe</item>
    <item>Africa</item>
</string-array>
```

Hope this helps!